# Using a Concurrent Queue to pass objects between two components of my applciation

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrent-queue

I have a program of mine which makes use of the c# concurrent Queue to pass data from my one component to the other.

Component 1:
   Multiple network connections receive data and then put it into this Queue

Component 2:
 Reads data from this queue and then processes it.

Ok, good all makes sense ( I sure hope).

Now what I want to know, is what is the best / most efficient way to go about passing the data between the two components?

Option 1:
Poll the queue for new data in component 2? Which will entail blocking code, or atleast a `while(true)`

Option 2:
I don't know if this is possible, but that's why im here asking. Does the queue data structure not have a sort of functionality that say my component 2 can register to the queue to be notified of any inserts / changes? This way whenever data is added it can just go fetch it, and I can then avoid any blocking / polling code.

Comment: What is *component* (could be [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx))? Class? How do you use this class? Simplest approach to pass data is to use event and wrap data into `EvengArgs`. But it could be also good to have *argumentless* events (when you retrive data from `sender` or from instance, which is accessible somehow).

Comment: Would events not serve for this purpose?

Comment: @Sinatr component is just a theoretical name I chose to represent the application on a higher level.

Comment: The blocking approach is traditional in a Producer/Consumer scheme, use a BlockingCollection (wrapper).

Comment: This way whenever data is added it can just go fetch it' - how would it know to go fetch it?  To fire an event on a consumer thread, the consumer would require an event-dispatching loop, ie. it would have to wait on a blocking queue for messages.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component 1 ( Producer) require either manual or automatic blocking since you anticipate multiple access (multiple post mentioned) while producing. This means BlockingQueue make sense in Component1. However, in Component 2 (Consumer), if you think you only (at any time) have one consumer then you don’t need any blocking code.

In order to save or avoid while, you must need a mechanism to inform the consumer that someone has added something into the queue. This can be achieved using a custom eventing (not talking about EventHandle subtypes). Keep in mind, you may not have the element order in such style of eventing.

Comment: Yes you are correct, Multiple producers single consumer

Comment: @Zapnologica, To complete, you can go with option 2, where encapsulate the a custom eventing in you consumer 1 implementation, where an event will be fired when an item is added into a queue. And then subscribe for this event in your Component 2. Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple implementation of Producer/Consumer you can try using [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For a more complex consumption of data from from various sources [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/gg577609.aspx) might help. It's a much steeper learning curve but it is a very powerful pull based framework, so you don't need to do any polling.

Comment: Ok so basically what you are saying, Unless I want to get heavily complicated blocking is a sufficient solution?